# Activity (Loader - downloading) + 3 Fragments (with Loaders - computation)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, fragment, loader

I have to download "raw" data from the server every N seconds and then deliver it to fragments (which are inside ViewPager). Every fragment has to do its own computation on the data and then populate own RecyclerView. 
I have one idea how to achieve that:

1. `Activity's AsyncTaskLoader` downloads data, store it and then
   broadcasts an `Intent` that new data has come.
2. Every `fragment` has its own `AsyncTaskLoader` and connected `broadcast receiver`.
3. When `fragment's Loader` receives information about new data, get it form the `activity`, compute and deliver to `RecyclerView`

Is it the proper solution? Is there simpler approach to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Service which contain a Runnable code to download "raw" data from the server every N seconds.
Save received data in Singleton, and you can compute and deliver directly to your RecyclerView's adapter

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTaskLoader in the Activity is a good idea, but I would simplify communication with the fragments by using a message bus instead of broadcasting intents.